# htaccess for subdirectory only

Tags: .htaccess

i have a some directory on my www folder

-www (base)

--folder1

--folder2

--folder3

so i want to use some htaccess code for all files and folder (so i just create .htaccess in www folder)

but also i want to  add this code just for folder 1,2,3 (and files inside them)  and no for other folders or other files in base directory www or other directory

```
  RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule \.m3u8 file.m3u8 [NC,L]


 #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(vlc|LibVLC|Android|iPhone).*$ [NC]
  #  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `RewriteCond` to restrict your first rule for certain folders only:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(folder1|folder2|folder3)/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule \.m3u8 file.m3u8 [NC,L]

# remaining rules go here
```